# In Java, main method returns value 64 rather than 100 . why is this happening?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String str[]){// String type
    System.out.println("Main()");
    main(0100);}
public static void main(int a){//integer type
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

answer should be 100 rather 64

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if you put a `0` before a primitive literal, it is interpretted as octal. 100 in octal is 64 in decimal.